# Graphic of ButtonCell ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-8

The user is given a choice of two figures (Circle and Square). 
The ComboBox may also have an Empty choice. 
The graphic for the Button of ComboBox are displayed only if the enum element is added to the ComboBox.

I want the user to be able to choose from only two shapes, so I am not adding an Empty option as an element of the ComboBox.

The problem : when the Empty option is selected, the **line** does not appear on the Button.

```
enum Shapes{
    Circle, Square, Empty;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    ComboBox<Shapes> shapeBox = new ComboBox<>();
    shapeBox.setCellFactory(param-> new ShapeListCell());
    shapeBox.setButtonCell(new ShapeListCell());

    shapeBox.getItems().add(Shapes.Circle);
    shapeBox.getItems().add(Shapes.Square);
    //shapeBox.getItems().add(Shapes.Empty);
    shapeBox.setValue(Shapes.Empty);

    Button clearBtn = new Button("Clear selection");
    clearBtn.setOnAction(e->shapeBox.setValue(Shapes.Empty));

    HBox root = new HBox(shapeBox,clearBtn);
    root.setSpacing(10);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400,200);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


private class ShapeListCell extends ListCell<Shapes> {
    double r = 10;
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Shapes item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());

            switch (item) {
            case Circle:
                setGraphic(new Circle(r, r, r));
                break;
            case Empty:
                setGraphic(new Line(0, r, r*2, r));
                break;
            case Square:
                setGraphic(new Rectangle(r*2, r*2));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When **Empty** is added to the ComboBox:

[image]

When **Empty** is NOT added to the ComboBox:

[image]

I use java version "1.8.0_202"

Answer (score 3):

[It's a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221722): ComboBoxListViewSkin does very dirty stuff when trying to configure the buttonCell for an uncontained value. One culprit is updateDisplayText which changes text/graphic property of the buttonCell under its feet, that is without going through updateItem:

```
final StringConverter<T> c = comboBox.getConverter();
final String promptText = comboBox.getPromptText();
String s = item == null && promptText != null ? promptText :
           c == null ? (item == null ? null : item.toString()) : c.toString(item);
// here it sets the text - this is why the "Empty" is showing initially
cell.setText(s);
// here it unconditionally nulls the graphic - this is why the line never shows up
cell.setGraphic(null);
```

To hack around, we need a very special cell that is aware of that misbehaviour and does its best (which obviously is highly implementation dependent, so beware!) to cope with it. Basically, it must do two thingies

- special case its state in updateItem when it is in the role of a buttonCell and the combo's value is not contained in the list
- and take care of its initial state and revert any initial fiddling from the skin

the former hooks in whenever the uncontained value is selected later in the combo's lifetime, the latter is needed due to the skin's "early" lazy internal configuration.

An example cell:

```
public class ShapeListCell2 extends ListCell<Shapes> {
    double r = 10;
    Circle circle = new Circle(r, r, r);
    Line line = new Line(0, r, r*2, r);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(r*2, r*2);
    ComboBox<Shapes> combo;
    InvalidationListener gl = obs -> graphicUpdated();

    /**
     * Use this constructor in the combo's cellFactory.
     */
    public ShapeListCell2() {
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     * Use this constructor when being the button cell.
     * @param combo
     */
    public ShapeListCell2(ComboBox combo) {
        this.combo = combo;
        if (isButtonCell()) {
            // initialize with empty text/graphic
            resetButtonCell();
            // register listener to reset on first nulling by skin
            graphicProperty().addListener(gl);
        }
    }

    private void graphicUpdated() {
        // remove listener
        graphicProperty().removeListener(gl);
        resetButtonCell();
    }

    protected void resetButtonCell() {
        setText(Shapes.Empty.toString());
        setGraphic(line);
    }

    protected boolean isButtonCell() {
        return combo != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Shapes item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        // special case: buttonCell with uncontained value
        if (isButtonCell() && getIndex() < 0 && combo.getValue() != null) {
            resetButtonCell();
            return;
        }
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());
            switch (item) {
            case Circle:
                setGraphic(circle);
                break;
            case Empty:
                setGraphic(line);
                break;
            case Square:
                setGraphic(rect);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware: this is a hack for fx11+, seems like it doesn't help on the fx8 as per feedback by OP.

Note that I moved all node instantiation out off updateItem - it must not have any heavy load :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and quick answer, I tried your code. This works, but when I select an item from the list and then click the "Clear selection" button, the line does not appear again.

Comment: hmm .. worksforme .. which fx version are you using?

Comment: I use java version "1.8.0_202"

Comment: as with all hacks that rely on  implementation details, that might and probably does ( mine is fx11, won't try for such an outdated version as fx8) make a big difference ;) Since then, the skins were moved into public scope and quite a bunch of bugs fixed .. so this cannot be more a starting point for you.